# Why does the pen does not move straight?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

If i put a pen on a table in its horizontal position and then i try to move it horizontally by giving it a small push, so that it would fall off a table, i expect it to move horizontally but my pen ( and all other pens too! ) moves diagonally when it starts moving down the table!When i remove the notebook , the pen moves like,its shown in the picture ( if i keep it horizontally also, it gives the same result)-

[image]

Why does this happen? Why does it not move horizontally ?

Comment: Some counter questions.. Where do you apply the force? Is the chassis's structure tapered (an exaggeration would be cone)? Other reasons could be non uniform horizontal mass distribution.

Comment: Do you know motion Of centre of mass which are uniform or nonuniform

Comment: Your picture is not large enough or clear enough to see what the pen looks like and your statements are incomplete (and possibly wrong :-) ). You say your pen is a cylinder. Does it look [**like this**](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e1/Cylinder_geometry.svg/220px-Cylinder_geometry.svg.png) with r constant at ALL points along its body, or at some points is R different than at others. If r is larger at and point to the left of the right hand end than it is AT the right hand end then you would expect it to move as you have shown.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon My pen is cylindrical if you take out the cone part!

Comment: Aaryan - IF it has anything other than a **purely**  cylindrical form when it is rolled then it must roll in a "non-straight" path - for the reasons given by Pela.

Comment: I have downvoted your question because at present it seems that the pen, when it is rolled, is not a pure cylinder, but you have failed to provide more details when asked to.  At the moment the question is wasting people's time because it is unclear. When you clarify the question adequately I will remove my down vote and may give it an upvote depending on what information you supply.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because your pen is not a [cylinder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cylinder_%28geometry%29), but a portion of a [cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone). Since it is also [rigid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_body), both ends have to complete one cycle of rolling simultaneously. This means that for each cycle, if the narrow and thick ends are separated by the pen's length $L$ and have radii $r_1$ and $r_2$, respectively, they roll $2\pi r_1$ and $2\pi r_2$, respectively. The only way this can be accomplished (without skidding) is for the ends to roll in a cicrcular motion around a common center.

If I haven't miscalculated, then the distance $d$ from the "small" end to this center is
$$d = \frac{L}{r_2/r_1–1}$$.

[image]

Comment: If i remove the cone part of the pen and then move it in the similar way, then also, it moves in a circular path. I understand what you say , but that does not gives me an answer to the WHY part! Why does it not move horizontally?
My pen is a also a cylinder .

Comment: Most pens are conical even withour their cap. Even a small difference in radii could be noticable. If you have a caliper and a ruler, you can measure and see if it fits the formula I just added. If not, then I'd go for a misalinged table, or, perhaps, density differences.

Comment: I am just asking why does it bend? not how but WHY?
Why doesn’t it moves horizontally?

Comment: @AaryanDewan: I'm sorry, I don't understand the difference. I understand that _if_ your pen is perfectly homogeneous and cylindrical, and your table isn't crooked, and the distance from your system to the nearest black hole can be neglected, then this doesn't answer your question, but otherwise I'm a bit confused.